# getJSON doesnt work when trying to retrieve echoed data from php script

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, wordpress

I spent multiple hours of figuring out how to solve this issue also by reading similiar posts on stackoverflow.com but I cant figure out how to do it.

So for your info im using Wordpress as CMS.

I have a php script (**getlocations.php**) which returns an encoded JSON-object of a twodimensional array:

```
// getlocations.php
<?php

$returnarray = array();

$returnarray[0] = array();
$returnarray[0]['name'] = "Peter";
$returnarray[0]['city'] = "NYC";
$returnarray[1]['name'] = "Dave";
$returnarray[1]['city'] = "NYC";

echo json_encode($returnarray);

?>
```

Now I want to use the data on my site and use javascript for further processing.
So I took a Wordpress-Codeblock and put this code in:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){

               console.log("Test");
               $.getJSON('getlocations.php', function(data) {
                      console.log(data);
                      console.log("Test2");  
                      // do something with the data                             
               });    
       });
</script>
```

The console prints out "Test" but nothing more.
Could it have something to do with wordpress?

Comment: F12 to open developer tools, click the Network tab, make the request happen.  Check the request in the developer tools to see what response code it returns.

Comment: Helped me alot thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress use the full URL path of the file. For example If getlocations.php is in template use the get_template_directory_uri function.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){

               console.log("Test");
               $.getJSON('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/getlocations.php', function(data) {
                      console.log(data);
                      console.log("Test2");  
                      // do something with the data                             
               });    
       });
</script>
```

Comment: @Samuel Dressel, where is the json file in wordpress?